# Magento - Admin missing CSS

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've copied my magento site locally so I can work on it, everything is setup fine, but the admin side the css is missing.

When looking at the view source I can see it's missing my domain part i.e. http://www2.magento.com:8080/admin so it's just trying to access everything in the root: so it's /adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css

Does anybody know how to resolve this, I've cleared the cache within var/cache.

I'm just about to throw the laptop out the window, kick the bin over then put my head through a wall! :-)

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok done it :)

in my windows host file I setup:

127.0.0.1 magento.localhost.com www.localhost.com

Then within magento .htaccess I did
RewriteBase /magento/